# List unpublished masters thesis in preprints section on CV?

Tags: publications, thesis, cv, preprint

After I've defended my masters thesis, if I haven't published it anywhere, should I list it in the preprints section on my CV?

Comment: Well, that begs the question: do you have a preprint?

Comment: @Kimball yep, I had to publish papers before even starting my thesis, so I alredy have publications and preprints on my CV.

Comment: I think that, if a thesis is put on a preprint repository even before you defend for your degree, it is actually not *unpublished* anymore. It is published and available to your academic community.

Comment: I meant a preprint of your thesis.  (I interpreted your statement as meaning you haven't had it submitted and approved by your committee, but maybe you mean something else?)

Comment: @Kimball your first interpretation was correct. At my university there's only a certain time frame before they accept them for review, and it hasn't come yet. So, I only have the unsubmitted manscript on my hard drive and on my google drive for public viewing (if they have the link).

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent It's not on any preprint repository just my google drive, so the person reading my resume may read it.

Comment: I'm not sure which question you're asking: "Does it belong in the preprints section?" or "Does it even belong on my CV yet?" I could potentially see two different answers. At any rate, you could always say "To be submitted XX/YY/ZZZZ" or something to that effect, especially if it's done and just waiting to be submitted.

Comment: @pjs36 I'm asking of it's to be put on the preprints section

Comment: Can you please clarify the state of your thesis?  I'm quite confused.

Comment: @jakebeal finish but unsubmitted, and will remain that way for a couple months

Comment: Unsubmitted to what?

Comment: @jakebeal my university for review, for wherever theses go to get reviewed.

Comment: I, honesty, didn't think this question would be this difficult to answer :/

Comment: PhD? Masters? Undergraduate? Do you have a committee?

Comment: @jakebeal Master's.. I have 3 external examiners which they need to be sent to.

Comment: **Yes.**  Once your masters thesis in a state where you are ready to share it, I recommend that you upload it to the arXiv or some other public preprint server.  At that point, it makes good sense to list your thesis on your CV.  Some people use a specific section called "Theses and Dissertations", but if you have only one, it may make sense just to list among your preprints.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9082/22733) addresses how to list a thesis on your CV, but generally is speaking about dissertations that have already been completed.  The basic conclusion is to list theses in their own separate section.

For your situation, with a nearly complete dissertation, it would be appropriate to list it the same way, but for its date list the future date when it is anticipated to be finalized.  This would look something like:

> Master's Dissertation: *thesis title*, September 2016 (anticipated).