# Do you include your thesis on a "publication list"?

Tags: job-search

I am currently on the job market in an academic field (mathematics). Several of the jobs I am applying to ask for a "publication list," distinct from the CV. My CV of course lists publications, and lists my PhD thesis separately, in the "education" section, under my degree. (Per this question: [Can dissertation be included in publication part in CV](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9082/can-dissertation-be-included-in-publication-part-in-cv))

Is a separate "publication list" also supposed to include the thesis?

Comment: Well, was your thesis published?

Comment: I mean, it's in ProQuest...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a clear universal definition of what should go on a "publication list".  It's possible they only want peer-reviewed research publications, it's possible they want other works as well.

So the best approach, in my opinion, is to create a publication list with multiple sections.  Have one section for "traditional" peer-reviewed research publications, and one or more additional sections for other works of yours that have been made publicly available (hence "publications" according to some definitions) but not in typical peer-reviewed venues.  You might lump these all together under "other works", or if appropriate for your body of work, you could have sections like "dissertation", "posters", "preprints", "popular articles", "lecture notes", "technical reports", etc.

You can do the same on your CV.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Sure, they are reviewed by a committee of faculty / examiners / etc.  But regardless of semantics, the term "peer reviewed" is generally understood *not* to include this process for theses.